# Error creating device database

Tags: dxa

After executing the following command:

```
D:\Applications\Tridion\DataStore\bin>java -Xmx1024m -jar lib\cwd_engine.jar https://context.sdl.com/seed
```

I end up with this while creating the device database.

> Cannot execute context repository manager
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Build ID has not been provided by
>   service in he ader X-Context-Build-Id or x-context-service-build-id. 
>   Available headers are
>           at com.sdl.context.engine.knowledge.ContextKnowledgeLoader.openConnectio
>   n(ContextKnowledgeLoader.java:350) ~[cwd_engine.jar:7.1.2-1706]
>           at com.sdl.context.engine.knowledge.ContextKnowledgeLoader.loadFromUrl(C
>   ontextKnowledgeLoader.java:283) ~[cwd_engine.jar:7.1.2-1706]
>           at com.sdl.context.engine.knowledge.ContextKnowledgeLoader.load(ContextK
>   nowledgeLoader.java:109) ~[cwd_engine.jar:7.1.2-1706]
>           at com.sdl.context.engine.repository.ContextRepositoryManager.loadContex
>   tKnowledgeFile(ContextRepositoryManager.java:239)
>   ~[cwd_engine.jar:7.1.2-1706]
>           at com.sdl.context.engine.repository.ContextRepositoryManager.importCont
>   extKnowledge(ContextRepositoryManager.java:151)
>   ~[cwd_engine.jar:7.1.2-1706]
>           at com.sdl.context.engine.repository.ContextRepositoryManager.execute(Co
>   ntextRepositoryManager.java:125) ~[cwd_engine.jar:7.1.2-1706]
>           at com.sdl.context.engine.repository.ContextRepositoryManager.main(Conte
>   xtRepositoryManager.java:63) ~[cwd_engine.jar:7.1.2-1706]

Please help me with this. Anybody have an idea what does it mean?

Answer (score 5):

To get the updated device database, your requesting server's IP address needs to be whitelisted with SDL. This is listed as step 1 in the documentation (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8E5F4BCD-E975-43A1-9884-BDD73D232195):

> Ensure that the IP address of the machine on which you wish to set up
>   the device database is on the white list managed by SDL. When in
>   doubt, contact SDL Customer Support for more information.

If you're trying the update on your localhost, or a server that hadn't been registered you will get an error, and this may be it.